# Error al pasar un proyecto symfony a otro ordenador

Tags: php, php7, symfony, composer, symfony4

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the
"C:\Users\adria\Desktop\App_AdvSoftware/.env" environment file. in
C:\Users\adria\Desktop\App_AdvSoftware\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php:505 Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\adria\Desktop\App_AdvSoftware\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php(60): 
Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad(false, Array) #1 
C:\Users\adria\Desktop\App_AdvSoftware\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php(80): 
Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load('C:\\Users\\adria\\...') #2 
C:\Users\adria\Desktop\App_AdvSoftware\config\bootstrap.php(17): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv- 
>loadEnv('C:\\Users\\adria\\...') #3 C:\Users\adria\Desktop\App_AdvSoftware\public\index.php(7): 
require('C:\\Users\\adria\\...') #4 {main} thrown in 
C:\Users\adria\Desktop\App_AdvSoftware\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php on line 505
```

Tenia el proyecto en un ordenador. Lo he pasado tal cual a otro y me da este error al abrir el proyecto en el navegador.
He instalado php, composer, git y symfony.
He hecho el comando `symfony check:requirements` y me pone `OK` así que está todo bien instalado el problema será de algun archivo caché dentro del proyecto o algo?

Comment: ¿Verificaste que el archivo `C:\Users\adria\Desktop\App_AdvSoftware/.env` existe? ¿Verificaste si tienes permiso de lectura sobre él?

Comment: Soy el usuario administrador, utilizo la consola como tal y .env sí que lo tengo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que al pasar el proyecto a otro ordenador, el .init se había trsnformado a _init y por eso no lo encontraba.
Gracias igualmente